# How to create a MVC data grid with million records in the most efficient manner with the help of store procedures

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I am developing a web Sites. I want to create a MVC web grid to show a result. The grid should have paging. I have doubts about the performance. I am using a store procedure to get data from the data base. I have millions of records in the data table that i want to show.I don't want to use Telerik.

My result class is like this.

```
    public class CallDetailTableRow
{
    public DateTime DateTime{get;set;}
    public string PhoneNo{get;set;}
    public int DurationMin { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Campaign { get; set; }
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Raiting{get; set;}

}
```

I want to show the data table with above same table headings.

1. How to do that?
2. How to  enhance the performance?

Answer (score 0):

There are various step that you can follow for performance be it on client site or server side
For server side don't go for Linq2Sql or Adoframework instead use ADO.net as they are just a wrapper over native ADO.net which makes data accessing slower.For client side you can create a script template which you can append to the table after ajax call on click of paging link.